# How to use docker to test multiple compiler versions

Tags: c++, docker, dockerfile

What is the idiomatic way to write a docker file for building against many different versions of the same compiler?

---

I have a project which tests against a wide-range of versions of different compilers like `gcc` and `clang` as part of a CI job. At some point, the agents for the CI tasks were updated/changed, resulting in newer jobs failing -- and so I've started looking into dockerizing these builds to try to guarantee better reliability and stability.

However, I'm having some difficulty understanding what a proper and idiomatic approach is to producing build images like this without causing a large amount of duplication caused by layers.

For example, let's say I want to build using the following toolset:

- `gcc` 4.8, 4.9, 5.1, ... (various versions)
- `cmake` (latest)
- `ninja-build`

I could write something like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs

# Parameterizing here possible, but would cause bloat from duplicated
# layers defined after this
FROM gcc:4.8 
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Set the work directory
WORKDIR /home/dev
COPY . /home/dev/

# Install tools (cmake, ninja, etc)
# this will cause bloat if the FROM layer changes
RUN <<EOF
  apt update
  apt install -y cmake ninja-build
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EOF

# Default command is to use CMak
CMD ["cmake"]
```

However, the installation of tools like `ninja-build` and `cmake` occur *after* the base image, which changes per compiler version. Since these layers are built off of a different parent layer, this would (as far as I'm aware) result in layer duplication for each different compiler version that is used.

One alternative to avoid this duplication could hypothetically be using a smaller base image like `alpine` with separate installations of the compiler instead. The tools could be installed first so the layers remain shared, and only the compiler changes as the last layer -- however this presents its own difficulties, since it's often the case that certain compiler versions may require custom steps, such as installing certain keyrings.

---

What is the idiomatic way of accomplishing this? Would this typically be done through multiple docker files, or a single docker file with parameters? Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not docker solution, but if you want to test out different versions of different compilers, have you looked at spack? It a "package manager" thingy, where you can (1) build and (2) load (by setting `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY` etc envvars) different packages (including different versions of compilers). So you can build gcc8,9,10, load gcc8, do stuff, unload gcc8, load gcc9, etc... Of course, dependencies are taken care of automagically!

Comment: Depending on how many compilers & versions you expect to have, perhaps I'd go with dockerfile for each compiler version, that can have whatever customization you need, plus a template dockerfile for each compiler, so that if there's no customization, the dockerfile for the version is generated from the template.

Comment: @Human-Compiler which CI tool are you using?

Comment: @root One of the main reasons I'm asking this question is to try to minimize the overhead of each docker layer. Changing out the base-image will cause each subsequent layer to bloat; as would, I'd expect, having N docker files for N toolchains. Is there really no way to install common tools like `cmake`/`ninja`/etc first into a separate layer, and then only have the toolchain layer change per image to minimize size?

Comment: @FabianHintringer The CI I'm using is completely inconsequential to this question, this is a question purely about Docker. I don't want to rely on the specifics of a single CI system.

Comment: Can you give us a working Dockerfile, please?

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara The code snippet I already have is effectively exactly what you're asking for, except truncated...? I'm asking how to write an idiomatic docker file that doesn't duplicate layer-sizes when working with multiple compilers. Changing the base image causes layer bloat, but would work. Ideally it would be installed via `apt install` or something; but this is not easy to homogeneously do with different compiler versions (such as older compilers that require legacy  apt repos)

Comment: I understood the question, but I cannot build the Dockerfile you posted. At this point, please give us the `docker build` command you use to build exactly that. I removed the `&& ...` at the end of the first `RUN` of course, but you are using `sudo`, which doesn't exist in this image, then `apt` is probably not installed either. Using a simple `docker build -t gcc4.8 .`, the building process fails. I am basically asking the Dockerfile you would use if you had to build the image for a single compiler.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara `apt` is installed with the `gcc` images; the `sudo` was the only thing that was unnecessary. Regardless, I've updated the dockerfile sample.

Comment: Thanks for updating it but I don't get why `docker run --rm -it gcc:4.8 bash -c "apt"` returns `bash: apt: command not found`, if `apt` is installed with `gcc` images.

Comment: I would have a single container that has all the versions you want, and then invoke the specific compiler version when building.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Ahhh, that's on me -- my apologies. `docker build` succeeded and I never checked the logs, so I assumed it worked. You are indeed correct that `apt` is not in a `gcc` image. That said, it doesn't really change the question itself

Comment: @Taekahn Your suggestion may be the most reasonable way to approach this in terms of layer-size, since the layer containing the compiler toolchains would be the sum weight of what could be N individual compiler toolchain layers. The only downside is for CI, this means each CI runner would have to download the same larger image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would separate the parts of preparing the compiler and doing the calculation, so the source doesn't become part of the docker container.

**Prepare Compiler**

For preparing the compiler I would take the ARG approach but without copying the data into the container. In case you wanna fast retry while having enough resources you could spin up multiple instances the same time.

```
ARG COMPILER=gcc:4.8
FROM ${COMPILER}
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Install tools (cmake, ninja, etc)
# this will cause bloat if the FROM layer changes
RUN <<EOF
  apt update
  apt install -y cmake ninja-build
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EOF

# Set the work directory
VOLUME /src
WORKDIR /src
CMD ["cmake"]
```

**Build it**

Here you have few options. You could either prepare a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) with the sources or use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) together with docker exec like this:

```
#bash style 
for compiler in gcc:4.9 gcc:4.8 gcc:5.1
do 
  docker build -t mytag-${compiler} --build-arg COMPILER=${compiler} .
  # place to clean the target folder
  docker run -v $(pwd)/src:/src  mytag-${compiler} 
done
```

And because the source is not part of the docker image you don't have bloat. You can also have two mounts, one for a readonly source tree and one for the output files.

Note: If you remove the CMake command you could also spin up the docker containers in parallel and use docker exec to start the build. The downside of this is that you have to take care of out of source builds to avoid clashes on the output folder.

Comment: Is it possible to pass an ARG via the image name?
Don't you need a `--build-arg Compiler=${compiler}` in the bash script?

Comment: @FabianHintringer You are absolutely right, that's for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

put an `ARG` before the `FROM` and then invoke the `ARG` as the `FROM`

so:

```
ARG COMPILER=gcc:4.8
FROM ${COMPILER}
# rest goes here
```

then you
`docker build . -t test/clang-8 --build-args COMPILER=clang-8`

or similar.

If you want to automate just make a list of compilers and a bash script looping over the lines in your file, and paste the lines as inputs to the tag and COMPILER build args.

As for Cmake, I'd just do:

```
RUN wget -qO- "https://cmake.org/files/v3.23/cmake-3.23.1-linux-"$(uname -m)".tar.gz" | tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C /usr/local
```

When copying, I find it cleaner to do

```
WORKDIR /app/build
COPY . .
```

edit: formatting

Comment: Wouldn't using an `ARG` in this scenario cause the very base layer to change for each docker image, thus making large images? The primary reason I'm asking is to try to minimize the overhead for the variations, which only changes for the compiler toolchain

Comment: Well, the way to minimize that would be to create a docker image that will run a script downloading all the compilers you want to test, and then using cmake  set the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` arguments to the different compilers and build the test program. But that is beyond the scope of the question I think.

Comment: The scope of the question is just about reducing layer sizes while using different compilers. As far as I can tell, the solution you've presented -- though I'm sure it works -- causes the same layer-bloat that I described in my question. I don't believe this would be considered "idiomatic" for docker, since generally the point is to keep each layer small and to build off of previous ones; whereas installing tools after changing the base-image means each image encodes identical duplicate layers.

Comment: Installing the compiler manually either via `apt install` or via a script would be ideal, but I'm unsure of how this can be done in a homogeneous way -- since many older compilers require additional steps to install.

Comment: not trying to argue with you, but using a script is not idiomatic to Docker per-se. If your needs are special in terms of compilers, I'd suggest installing a base image (cmake, ninja, sources) and then having separate dockerfiles that "inherit" from that template image. This does mean you'd have to hand-craft the images on a case-by-case basis. Although, I don't think this solves your bloat either

Comment: How is the accepted answer different from mine?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that easily and safely. You could use a [`RUN --mount=type=cache`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache), but the documentation clearly says that:

> Contents of the cache directories persist between builder invocations without invalidating the instruction cache. Cache mounts should only be used for better performance. Your build should work with any contents of the cache directory as another build may overwrite the files or GC may clean it if more storage space is needed.

I have not tried it but I guess the layers are duplicated anyway, you just save time, assuming the cache is not emptied.

---

The other possible solution you have is similar to the one you mention in the question: starting with the tools installation and then customizing it with the `gcc` image. Instead of starting with an `alpine` image, you could start `FROM scratch`. `scratch` is basically the empty image, you could `COPY` the files generated by

```
RUN <<EOF
  apt update
  apt install -y cmake ninja-build
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EOF
```

Then you `COPY` the entire `gcc` filesystem. However, I am not sure it will work because the order of the initial layers is now reversed. This means that some files that were in the `upper` layer (coming from tools) now are in the `lower` layer and could be overwritten. In the comments, I asked you for a working Dockerfile because I wanted to try this out before answering. If you want, you can try this method and let us know. Anyway, the first step is extracting the files created from the tools layer.

### How to extract changes from a layer?

Let's consider this Dockerfile and build it with `docker build -t test .`:

```
FROM debian:10
RUN apt update && apt install -y cmake && ( echo "test" > test.txt )
RUN echo "new test" > test.txt
```

Now that we have built the `test` image, we should find 3 new layers. You mainly have 2 ways to extract the changes from each layer:

- the first is `docker inspect`ing the image and then `find` the ids of the layers in the `/var/lib/docker` folder, assuming you are on Linux. Each layer has a `diff` subfolder containing the changes. Actually, I think it is more complex than this, that is why I would opt for...
- `skopeo`: you can install it with `apt install skopeo` and it is a very useful tool to operate on docker images. The command you are interested in is `copy`, that extracts the layers of an image and export them as `.tar`:

  ```
  skopeo copy docker-daemon:{image_name}:latest "dir:/home/test_img"
  ```

  where `image_name` is `test` in this case.

#### Extracting layer content with Skopeo

In the specified folder, you should find some `tar` files and a configuration file (look at the `skopeo copy` command output and you will know which one is that). Then extract each `{layer}.tar` in a different folder and you are done.

---

Note: to find the layer containing your tools just open the configuration file (maybe using `jq` because it is json) and take the `diff_id` that corresponds to the `RUN` instruction you find in the `history` property. You should understand it once you open the JSON configuration. This is unnecessary if you have a small image that has, for example, `debian` as parent image and a single `RUN` instruction containing the tools you want to install.

---

### Get GCC image content

Now that we have the tool layer content, we need to extract the `gcc` filesystem. we don't need `skopeo` for this one, but `docker export` is enough:

- create a container from `gcc` (with the tag you need):

  ```
  docker create --name gcc4.8 gcc:4.8
  ```
- export it as tar:

  ```
  docker export -o gcc4.8.tar gcc4.8
  ```
- finally extract the tar file.

---

### Putting all together

The final Dockerfile could be something like:

```
FROM scratch
COPY ./tools_layer/ /
COPY ./gcc_4.x/ /
```

In this way, the tools layer is always reused (unless you change the content of that folder, of course), but you can parameterize the `gcc_4.x` with the `ARG` instruction for example.

**Read carefully**: all of this is not tested but you might encounter 2 issues:

- the `gcc` image overwrites some files you have changed in the tools layer. You could check if this happens by computing the `diff` between the gcc layer folder and the tools layer folder. If it happens, you can only keep track of that file/s and add it/them in the dockerfile after the `COPY ./gcc ...` with another `COPY`.
- When in the `upper` layer a file is removed, docker marks that file with a `.wh` extension (not sure if it is different with `skopeo`). If in the tools layer you delete a file that exists in the gcc layer, then that file will not be deleted using the above Dockerfile (the `COPY ./gcc ...` instruction would overwrite the `.wh`). In this case too, you would need to add an additional `RUN rm ...` instruction.

---

This is probably not the correct approach if you have a more complex image that the one you are showing us. In my opinion, you could give this a try and just see if this works out with a single Dockerfile. Obviously, if you have many compilers, each one having its own tools set, the maintainability of this approach could be a real burden. Instead, if the Dockerfile is more or less linear for all the compilers, this might be good (after all, you do not do this every day).

Now the question is: is avoiding layer replication so important that you are willing to complicate the image-building process this much?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the detail/information you put into this answer! The main reason I wanted to reduce layer sizes is to minimize the cost of the entire image for hosting purposes due to file-size limits. Perhaps that's just not a good reason, though -- given the amount of difficulty it seems to result in as you have identified.

Comment: Docker image building is based on the union filesystem concept and reordering layers as you want goes against it. In this case, giving up on the storage size reduction is probably the most reasonable choice.